# How to create a rounded button to support in all the browsers?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I m using ASP.NET and C#.Now i need to create rounded button that need to be support in all different browser. But Visual studio is not supporting this property.

Where am i going wrong?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I did used this.

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
```

But no luck.

**Update:**

Thanks. After installing sp1 it worked.

Comment: Where do you see this error ? In a browser or in Visual Studio ?

Comment: can someone tell me how to get upvote for this question? Because i did changed the post but no response. I lost my access for asking question.Then is it possible to recover state from closed.

Comment: +1 as encouragement but the main point for you would be to improve the quality of your questions. I'd recommend you to have a look at a few discussions on meta regarding the quality of questions : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=question+quality

Comment: Thanks,Then do i need alter the same post? or may i change this to different question, Because some of them were already answered for this.

Comment: I hope it increases the quality some what..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `border-radius` property is only available in not too ancestral browsers.

See [the compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius).

If you're using an old IDE based on IE8, you can't easily get all the niceties of CSS3.

[SP1 solves some of the compatibility problems of Visual Studio 2010.](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.fr/2011/06/announcing-html5-css3-support-for.html)

Comment: Did you install SP1 ? It should solve the problem.

Comment: k.thanks..but i dont have permission to install anything in this system..so i will try later..

Answer (score 2):

As border-radius property is not available & Visual Studio is giving error but it will work definitely because I also use it regularly.

Answer (score 2):

I would not worry about the error shown in VS if it will let you commit the code, I am sure it either needs updating or will not except certain attributes. I get errors from this IDE usually when putting in Gradients.

One thing I will say is that I would always put prefixes in as well for the older versions of the compliant browsers like early versions of firefox etc.

```
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
     border-radius: 15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Border Radius differs in browsers

-moz-border-radius: 15px; for firefox

border-radius: 15px; for IE

See http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/ for more info on CSS Rounded Corners